How to sort my Plotly Bargraph based on values in Descending order in R?
I have the following bar chart that is plugged into shiny app in order to get a drop down filter of state
My data set is already sorted by top 20 cities based on the state.
This is what my code looks like so far:
  crime_stat <- crime_stat |>
  arrange(state)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Top 20 Cities by State & Incident Counts"),
  selectInput("stateInput", "Choose a State:", 
              choices = unique(crime_stat$state)),
  plotlyOutput("incidentPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Reactive expression to filter the data-set based on 
  # selected state and calculate top 20 cities
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    crime_stat |>
      filter(state == input$stateInput) |>
      group_by(city_or_county) |>
      summarise(incidents = n(), .groups = 'drop') |>
      slice_max(n = 20, order_by = incidents) |>
      arrange(desc(incidents))
  })

  # Render the plot using Plotly
  output$incidentPlot <- renderPlotly({
    fig <- plot_ly(data = filtered_data(), 
                   y = ~city_or_county, 
                   x = ~incidents, 
                   type = 'bar', 
                   orientation = 'h',
                   marker = list(color = 'steelblue')) |>
      layout(title = paste("Top 20 Cities in", input$stateInput, "by Incident Counts"),
             xaxis = list(title = "Number of Incidents", categoryorder = "total descending"),
             yaxis = list(title = "City or County", automargin = TRUE))
    fig
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

This is a screenshot of what my output looks like.

I have 2 issues here:

How do I get the graph to sort in descending based on the values of the number of incidents? (this I believe is an issue with Shiny, the solution provided in other threads does not give me the right solution.)
How do I increase the shiny app size in my HTML window? (I tried googling but didn't find any good results) I tried editing the {r} portion of the code and included fig.height=15 but it did not work.

The dataset I have used it from here https://github.com/jamesqo/gun-violence-data

I DISAGREE THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION....THERE IS NO ANSWER FOR THIS!
